# getting the issue with "unsupported grant_type" while trying for auth token

Tags: swift

Getting the issue with

> unsupported grant_type

while trying for auth token.

Passing params as :

```
let payloadParams = ["grant_type" : "password",
                            "username" : "some@gmail.com",
                            "password" : "some",
                            "domain-name" : "some.Database"]
```

Call is :

```
NetworkInterface.fetchJSON(.autharization, headers:nil, payload: payloadParams, requestCompletionHander: {(success, data, response,error)
```

Header is :

```
["Content_Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"].
```

Comment: Hay sharad chauhan...do you have any idea about this.

Comment: check the key grant_type. Try to hit request from postman and check if its working. Also headers is nil in your call.

Comment: header are passing later in the code...getting response from postrman

Comment: Add a screenshot of postman request.